# Order version in session greater than Repository Item Version

Tags: atg

I have seen some occurrences of `InvalidVersionException` in our logs where the version of the Order object in session (OrderHolder) is greater than the version in the cache (Repository Item version).  under what scenario could this occur?  My understanding is that we usually get this InvalidVersionException if we modify and update Order outside of transaction in which case the version in the cache would be greater than version stored in the order memory.

Comment: I see that you have asked multiple questions, all of which will probably have the same resolution.  I would suggest you try to consolidate all your questions into one question, listing all the symptoms (or errors).

Answer (score 1):

There is a very well-established pattern to updating the Order. Any code where you update the order yourself (outside of, say, the standard purchase process form handlers) must do the following.

1. Get write lock on Profile
2. Begin Transaction
3. Synchronise on Order
4. Modify Order
5. Call `order.updateVersion()`
6. Call `OrderManager.updateOrder()`
7. Release Order synchronisation
8. End Transaction
9. Release Profile lock

If you do not follow this, you can end up with these kinds of errors.

See http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/atg/design-pattern-for-updating-an-atg-order.html